# Any non-recursive definitions for a binary tree?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Edit: Is it possible to non-recursively define a (possibly infinite) binary tree? Here is my attempt with partial functions $L$ and $R$ on the set of natural numbers $N$ with nodes numbered by $N$

1. $\forall x,y:[L(x)=y \implies x,y\in N]$
2. $\forall x,y\in N: [L(x)=L(y) \implies x=y]$
3. $\forall x,y:[R(x)=y \implies x,y\in N]$
4. $\forall x,y\in N: [R(x)=R(y) \implies x=y]$
5. $n\in N$
6. $\forall x\in N: [L(x)\neq n \land R(x)\neq n]$
7. $\forall x,y\in N: [L(x)=y => \forall z\in N: R(z)\neq y]\space\space$
   (Edit)
8. $\forall x,y\in N: [R(x)=y => \forall z\in N: L(z)\neq y]\space\space$
   (Edit)

where

$L(x)=y$ means $y$ is the *left* child of node $x$

$R(x)=y$ means $y$ is the *right* child of node $x$

$n$ is the *root* node

Comment: Does this allow cycles for the $R$ or $L$ function? In particular, can one have $L(x)=x$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No. See changes. Thanks.

Comment: Also made L and R injective.

Comment: Does this allow cycles for the $R$ or $L$ function? In particular, can one have $R(R(x))=x$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown There shouldn't be. Yes, it requires a proof.

Comment: I don't think one will be forthcoming from these axioms.

Comment: Removed $L(x)\neq x$ and $R(x)\neq x$. Injectivity should make them redundant.

Comment: Do you intend to have all trees required to be infinite?

Comment: @BenjiAltman No.

Answer (score 3):

No, these axioms are far too weak.  For instance, you could have $N=\{n,a,b\}$ where $a=L(b)$ and $b=L(a)$.

Note that more generally, it will be impossible to give any first-order axiomatization of binary trees over the language $\{L,R,n\}$.  The statement that every element is obtained from $n$ by finitely many applications of $L$ and $R$ cannot be expressed in first-order logic (e.g., by compactness).

Comment: N is set of natural numbers.

Comment: @DanChristensen But the natural numbers can't be pinned down in a first-order way. By the compactness theorem, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a set of connected graphs of unbounded diameter (such as binary trees), then $\mathcal{C}$ is not first-order axiomatizable: any set of sentences true of every graph in $\mathcal{C}$ will *also* be true of some disconnected graph.

Comment: Of course, this just rules out *first-order* axiomatizations. If you want to give yourself the ability to talk about the true natural numbers right at the start, then things are doable. But to me this just pushes the question back: if you're relying on a "true" copy of the naturals, then it feels to me like you need to give a "recursion-free" construction of $\mathbb{N}$ to be truly satisfied.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Of course I am relying on The Set of Natural Numbers as defined by Peano's Axioms (quantifying over subsets of N for induction).

Comment: If you can't see how to generalize my example to one where the underlying set is the natural numbers, then I don't believe you've actually given any thought to what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

How about we don't have $N$ be the natural numbers, and we consider $R(x) = n$ to mean $x$ has no right child, and $L(x) = n$ to be $x$ has no left child, and $n$ is the root of the tree. These axioms do allow for infinite trees however I think it captures everything else. Realize when I say $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ I really mean $\forall x \in N$ and $\exists x \in N$.

- $n \in N$

  - This insists the tree is not empty, and contains a root, $n$.
- $\forall x,y[(R(x) = R(y) \land R(x) \not=n )\implies x=y ]$

  - From this every $x\in N$ with a right child is the only element of $N$ with that right child.
- $\forall x,y[(L(x) = L(y) \land L(x) \not=n )\implies x=y ]$

  - From this every $x\in N$ with a left child is the only element of $N$ with that left child.
- $\forall x[x\not=n \implies (\exists y[R(y) = x] \iff \lnot\exists y[L(y)=x])$

  - From this every $x \not=n \in N$, $x$ is either a right child of some node, or a left child of some node, but not both.

This does allow for infinite binary trees, but does not require trees be infinite.